# Modify context param from servlet code

Tags: java, jsf-2

I know how to get the context params, but is there a way to change the value of the context params defined in the `web.xml`? I'm using JSF so in this case it will be `FacesContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can and should not change them programmatically. It would defeat their purpose. Just change them straight in the `web.xml`, or look for a different solution --which I can't suggest as the concrete functional requirement behind this need is unclear. I can at least hint that some specific context parameters are overrideable by JNDI, for example the [`javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#getProjectStage%28%29).